# Hibernate commiting changes to database on lock?

Tags: java, hibernate

I had some limited previous knowledge about Hibernate and what it is supposed to do, but currently I find myself having to mantain a JSF web application that makes intensive use of it, and it's becoming very difficult for me to accomplish several of what should be near-to-trivial tasks.

My current issue is trying to avoid making permanent changes into the database in a record that one shouldn't have permission to edit. It's displayed via a regular form, and there is an external service (which is working properly) that informs if the data should be modified or not.

The problem is that the current existing code workflow automatically saves data when one browse from one screen to the next or the previous one, or even jumping between screens in a sort of breadcrumbs menu.

I've tried some approaches, the simplest one disabling the form when one doesn't have permission to do so. Haven't accomplished that at all, although I was close, but switched to avoiding saving the modified data into database, as it was something I had to do anyway as a method to prevent cheap "hackers" messing with the HTML code and enabling the form and so. So my current approach is to repopulate the object from the database in those places I've detected it's going to be saved or updated into it, prior to doing so. It's not elegant, but it's the easiest and the more straightforward method I could think of without messing up too much with the existing, legacy code.

I have two problems with this approach. One is that I get an "org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" Hibernate exception when I try to manually save the object once I've repopulated it with the original value. But this is not to subject of this question, as I am already searching for infor about it.

The main problem is that there are places where the changes are being written into database even though there is no explicit previous save() method (or so) being used, or I'm not able to find it, and it's a hell to debug as Hibernate is doing its "magic" besides the available code via reflection and so. After many hours, I've finally identified what seems to be causing the data to become permanent into the database:

```
    Session sess = getCurrentSession();
    sess.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(myDataObject);
```

To me this is really surprising. Either I'm not understanding what locking means, or how it works, or I'm missing some point, even thought I've read the docs about it. I've tried other LockOptions values, to the same result. But I'm 100% sure it's happening after the 2nd line above is executed as I'm querying the database directly and the changes are being made persistent into it just in that moment.

Can anyone tell me what's going on there and how to avoid this, and also maybe some guideliness on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Calling lock should **not** cause commit, I suggest you to check how you control the transaction(By annotation or manual call), 
post related code and try to remove unrelated description.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this, because you don't write how you retrieve persisted objects from the database, where your transaction boundaries / Hibernate session duration etc. are. Do you keep the session open between requests? You also seem to be surprised by Hibernate's approach to persistency: every change to a persisted object will be written to the database when the session is flushed (most often meaning, when the transaction is committed). No explicit "save" call is needed.

Comment: @Leisetreter, I see a `session.saveOrUpdate(sess)` and after that a `session.flush()`, which surprises me a bit as, according to what you said, the object would be written to the database twice... Am I right or maybe they are using a explicit save approach?

Comment: @Pere You should really read about the concepts of Hibernate to understand this. Quickly said, `session.saveOrUpdate(obj)` makes an object in JVM memory known to the Hibernate session. No writing database operation is happening at that time (this may be what surprises you). When the session is flushed (not necessarily by a `session.flush()` call), Hibernate compares the state the object was in when reading it from the db with the current state in memory and, if different, writes the changes to the database. Nothing so far is anything to do with locking, however.

Comment: @Leisetreter what really puzzles me out is that the code execution is NOT even running through the `session.flush()` I identified in the DAO related class. So there must be another one somewhere in the whole application code, which is getting really hard to identify to me. Thanks for the tips, although I'm still really stuck on this :(